# How to store values across google app script executions?

Tags: google-apps-script

How can I store a key value on first executions of a google app scripts and retrieve it at a later execution?

I thought about using the cache, but I'm unclear how long it will survive and there is quite some time between my last and my previous execution.

Thx, I really appreciate your help and expertise a lot!

Comment: In the case of Cache Service, you can set the expiration time of the cache. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache) And also, although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your situation, for example, Properties Service is useful for your situation? In this case, the clear expiration time is not set. I think that you can continue to use the key and value with the expiration time free. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties) If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike, thx a lot. Properties Service is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In the case of Properties service, there is the maximum size of the values. Please be careful this. You can see it at the official document. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) When you want to use more size, I would like to propose to use a text file and Google Docs files. When your issue was resolved, please post it as an answer. I think that it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Comment: @Tanaike, how would you allow a user to input his api keys to be stored in the user or document properties in a secure manner? It could not figure any way to set this properties eg via a admin ui similar to environment variables. Any ideas for this?

Comment: @Tanaike, added the follow up question regarding API credentials in a own question and added solution to this one. Thx for your help! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67807126/how-to-store-3rd-party-api-credentials-in-google-app-scripts-securely

Comment: About your new question, I noticed that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer. I think that it will resolve your new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thx to @Tanaike for providing solution as a comment.

Google App Scripts [PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties) provides the possibility to store variables in the context of the script, user or document which accesses it:

```
var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
userProperties.setProperties({
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2"
});
```