# How to store 3rd party api credentials in google app scripts securely

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm building a google app script which runs time based to retrieve data from a 3rd party api (non google service) and store it in a google sheet.

I'd like to allow multiple users to use this script. Thus every user should be able to provide his credentials to the script and these should be stored securely.

- How do I store 3rd party api credentials in google app scripts securely?
- How do I allow a user to input his api credentials?

Thx in advance, I really appreciate your expertise!

Comment: Not overly slick, but you could just make an extra sheet for API credentials and reference those cells in the script.

Comment: @Tom, likely works, but does not sound like a proper solution to me.

Answer (score 3):

*- How do I store 3rd party api credentials in google app scripts
securely?*

The [Properties Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties) in Google Apps Script is designed exactly for this use case. When your code calls the Properties Service to either store or fetch the API credentials, make sure that you use the **getUserProperties()** method. This will ensure that each user's credentials are stored securely in their own secret store.

*- How do I allow a user to input his api credentials?*

The [Ui Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui) in Google Apps Script allows you to generate user input dialogs. Specifically, you'll need to use the **prompt()** method of the Ui Class to accept user input.

Comment: I am using getUserProperties() to store my API keys but it seems that the spreadsheet is working within another context (different browser, different logged in google account). How could it be possible?